# Расписать выражение

Tags: c++

Всем привет, я только начинаю разбираться в С++, и не понял этого выражения в чужом коде:
`*(*(a + k+1) + i)`
Можете, пожалуйста, записать его в обычном виде?

Comment: `a[k + 1][i]` .

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, спасибо!

Comment: Это называется **разыменование указателя**